# scroll bar important query?

Tags: php, javascript, html

actually i downloaded code for scroll from.......
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
but when i added it in my page and add

using code ...
function addElement(url,imagePath){
alert(url);

alert(imagePath);

var container = document.getElementById('sncs');
items = container.getElementsByTagName("li");
//alert(items.length);

var new_element = document.createElement('li');

new_element.innerHTML ="";
//var raj='1'+new_element.innerHTML;
//alert()

```
new_element.className="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-4 jcarousel-item-4-horizontal";
//container.insertBefore(new_element, container.firstChild);
container.appendChild( new_element );
```

}

it added li not at the end but below scroll what will be the problem.....
Please help me to sort out this problem....

Comment: If you used any example from the site, which one did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly check your html and that you haven't left any tags open and have closed all "quotation marks". The easiest solution might be to start again as this problem could be down to a whole number of different things.